# How do I check if I'm running on Windows in Python?

Tags: python, platform, platform-specific

I found the platform module but it says it returns 'Windows' and it's returning 'Microsoft' on my machine. I notice in another thread here on stackoverflow it returns 'Vista' sometimes.

So, the question is, how do implemement?

```
if is_windows():
  ...
```

In a forward compatible way? If I have to check for things like 'Vista' then it will break when the next version of windows comes out.

---

Note: The answers claiming this is a duplicate question do not actually answer the question `is_windows`. They answer the question "what platform". Since many flavors of windows exist none of them comprehensively describe how to get an answer of `isWindows`.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196930/how-to-check-if-os-is-vista-in-python

Comment: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."  Alas, python gives us at least three ways..

Comment: Nit: [According to PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) you should prefer using the name `is_windows` over `isWindows`.

Answer (score 514, accepted):

Python [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module

Specifically for Python 3.6/3.7:

> `os.name`: The name of the operating
>   system dependent module imported. The
>   following names have currently been
>   registered: 'posix', 'nt', 'java'.

In your case, you want to check for 'nt' as `os.name` output:

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
     ...
```

There is also a note on `os.name`:

> See also [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.platform) has a finer granularity. [`os.uname()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.uname) gives
>   system-dependent version information.
>
> The [platform](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/platform.html#module-platform) module provides
>   detailed checks for the system’s identity.

Comment: 'nt' is the value for windows

Comment: What does linux normally return? posix?

Comment: @AndiJay - yes, but should be easy enough to test!

Comment: @MartinBeckett - Not necessarily. You may not have a machine running Linux available.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare you don't need a machine ;) https://onlinegdb.com/HyhJEzdX4 ( Well maybe in 2015 )

Comment: It turns out that `os.name` is actually not a good way. You want to use `platform.system()` instead. Here's the detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071295/207661

Comment: "... `'posix'`, `'nt'`, `'java'`" Of course, Windows can run java, so this quote in your answer shows that testing for `'nt'` is a bad way to test whether you're running on Windows.

Comment: What is the `'java'` OS ? Linux and Windows make sense but Java isn't an OS, is it ?

Comment: `system.uname()`, not `os.uname()` :)

Comment: @Haltarys, there were some phones running in `java`, before android became popular, I used to install games as `.jar` files, not sure if its anything like that.

Answer (score 88):

Are you using [`platform.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html)?

```
 system()
        Returns the system/OS name, e.g. 'Linux', 'Windows' or 'Java'.

        An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined.
```

If that isn't working, maybe try `platform.win32_ver` and if it doesn't raise an exception, you're on Windows; but I don't know if that's forward compatible to 64-bit, since it has 32 in the name.

```
win32_ver(release='', version='', csd='', ptype='')
        Get additional version information from the Windows Registry
        and return a tuple (version,csd,ptype) referring to version
        number, CSD level and OS type (multi/single
        processor).
```

But `os.name` is probably the way to go, as others have mentioned.

---

For what it's worth, here's a few of the ways they check for Windows in platform.py:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
#---------
if os.environ.get('OS','') == 'Windows_NT':
#---------
try: import win32api
#---------
# Emulation using _winreg (added in Python 2.0) and
# sys.getwindowsversion() (added in Python 2.3)
import _winreg
GetVersionEx = sys.getwindowsversion
#----------
def system():

    """ Returns the system/OS name, e.g. 'Linux', 'Windows' or 'Java'.    
        An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined.   
    """
    return uname()[0]
```

Comment: On a 64 bit machine, with Windows 7 (64 bit OS) this is the output:

    Python 3.1.1 (r311:74483, Aug 17 2009, 16:45:59) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    >>> print(sys.platform)
    win32
    >>> platform.win32_ver()
    ('post2008Server', '6.1.7100', '', 'Multiprocessor Free')

Note that the build explicitly calls it win32.

Comment: Oops, I thought the output would have been formatted better. hope you can read it anyway.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 52):

You should be able to rely on [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html).name.

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    # ...
```

edit: Now I'd say the clearest way to do this is via the [platform](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) module, as per the other answer.

Answer (score 43):

in sys too:

```
import sys
# its win32, maybe there is win64 too?
is_windows = sys.platform.startswith('win')
```

Comment: I'm on 64 bit Windows and this gives me 'win32' :)

Comment: @Hut8 I just noticed the same thing.

Comment: I'm kind of certain it usually returns 'win32' regardless; at least I've only seen checks for that in code I read.

Answer (score 22):

```
import platform
is_windows = any(platform.win32_ver())
```

or

```
import sys
is_windows = hasattr(sys, 'getwindowsversion')
```