# Automatic detection of display availability with matplotlib

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I'm generating matplotlib figures in a script which I run alternatively with or without a graphical display. I'd like the script to adjust automatically: with display, it should show the figures interactively, while without a display, it should just save them into a file.

From an answer to the question [Generating matplotlib graphs without a running X server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server), I learnt that one can use the Agg backend for non-interactive plotting.

So I am trying with this code:

```
import matplotlib
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    havedisplay = True
except:
    matplotlib.use("Agg")
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    havedisplay = False
# do the plotting
if havedisplay:
    plt.show()
else:
    fig.savefig("myfig.png")
```

This works as excepted in the case with a display. However, without a display, the call to `matplotlib.use` is not effective, since the display has already been chosen. It's clear that I should call `matplotlib.use` before `import matplotlib.pyplot`, but then I don't know how to test whether a display is available or not.

I have also tried with the experimental function `matplotlib.switch_backend` instead of `matplotlib.use`, but this generates a RuntimeError.

Does someone have an idea how to make the above code work as intended, or can suggest an alternative way to detect whether a display is available for matplotlib or not?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can detect directly if you have a display with the OS module in python.
in my case it's

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["DISPLAY"]
':0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simple and works for me. So here is what I do: first `import matplotlib`, then check whether `os.environ` has the key `"DISPLAY"`. If it has not, call `matplotlib.use("Agg")`. Then `import matplotlib.pyplot` and proceed.

Comment: This does not work in windows command line. When you run python from cmd, `plt.show()` opens a window with the plot. However, the `DISPLAY` key is not defined in the `os.environ` dict. So in this case the script writes to a file instead of opening an interactive window.

Comment: this will fail if "DISPLAY" is not defined. better to do `have_display = bool(os.environ.get('DISPLAY', None))`. That way, if DISPLAY is not defined or an empty string, `have_display` will be False

Answer (score 8):

The code below works for me in Linux and Windows (where it assumes there is a display device):

```
import os
import matplotlib
if os.name == 'posix' and "DISPLAY" not in os.environ:
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1325587/896111.

Note that the line `matplotlib.use('Agg')` must appear after the first import of `matplotlib` (otherwise you will get an error).

Answer (score 6):

try this?

```
import matplotlib,os
r = os.system('python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.figure()"')
if r != 0:
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.savefig('myfig.png')
else:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, also a very good solution. The suggestion by Oz123 seems more straightforward though.

Comment: I would prefer the combination of @JindraHelcl [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30513533/2164800) maybe even extended to save the `os.system` call through a `if os.name != 'posix' and not havedisplay:` condition, suggested by @eitanrich [in his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756291/2164800)

Answer (score 3):

By combining both of the approaches above, you'll get perhaps the best solution:

```
havedisplay = "DISPLAY" in os.environ
if not havedisplay:
    exitval = os.system('python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.figure()"')
    havedisplay = (exitval == 0)
```

The reason for this combo is that the run time of the `os.system` command may take a while. So when you are sure you have the display (judging by the `os.environ` value), you can save that time.
On the other hand, even if the `DISPLAY` key is not set in the `os.environ` variable, there is still a chance that the plotting methods will work with the graphical interface (e.g. when using Windows command line).

Comment: For anybody that is using multiple interpreter: You may want to use `os.system('{0} -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.figure()"'.format(sys.executable))` to choose the current interpreter. So it checks the right libraries (in case matplotlib is not installed on the one in `PATH`)

Answer (score 1):

when use GUI backend the figure object has show() method, you can use it to do the switch:

```
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use("Agg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
havedisplay = False
if hasattr(fig, "show"):
    plt.show()
else:
    print "save fig"
    fig.savefig("myfig.png")
```

Comment: Thanks, but without a display, I get an error already on the call to `plt.figure`: "Unable to access the X Display, ...".

Comment: `havedisplay = False` is not used

Comment: did you uncomment use("Agg") ?

Comment: @Oz123, when I uncomment the second line, the script runs into the "save fig" part both with and without a display, and does not show anything even with a display.

Comment: it does now show anything because in this example above there is nothing to show. Or you mean that in your code there is no output ?

Comment: also, see my answer above. does it help?

Comment: @Oz123, with a display, it should show the empty figure window. Anyway, you're other answer seems to be a good alternative. I'm going to try with this approach.

Comment: hi silvado, if it is working for you, please accept it as the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by @Oz123 generated a syntax error for me. However, i was able to easily detect the display using:

```
import os
havedisplay = "DISPLAY" in os.environ
#plotting...
```

That was the simplest thing i could find, anyway.

Comment: As I mentioned below @Oz123's answer, this does not work using python in windows command line.

Comment: this doesn't handle the case where DISPLAY is the empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
have_display = bool(os.environ.get('DISPLAY', None))
```

`have_display` is False if `DISPLAY` is not in the environment or is an empty string. otherwise, it's True