# System-wide matplotlib backend selection depending on display availability

Tags: python, ssh, matplotlib, backend

Let's say we have a computer that we access either locally or remotely (both with X server forwarding [`ssh -X`] and without it `ssh`).

When using matplotlib we probably want to use a different backend depending on the kind of session we're in. `Agg` when there is no X server so we get plots and not exceptions, and `TkAgg` when there is so we can play a bit more with our plots.

- You can set the default matplotlib backend through the `matplotlibrc` files both system-wide and user-wide.
- You can set [which backend you want to use for that script at its first lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) using `matplotlib.use` or even `matplotlib.rcParams`.

But all these are static solutions, that work well if **you always want to use the same backend (per computer, per user or even per script)**

If you want the backend to be chosen **in a given script** depending on the availability X server, you can check [the display at the beginning of the script and then load whichever backend you prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257385/automatic-detection-of-display-availability-with-matplotlib).
However, you need to insert this lines of code at the beggining of every script you want to run in both scenarios...

**Is there any way to select the backend depending on the availability of a display but as a configuration that applies system-wide or user-wide, for any script that is run?**
I'm thinking of something like a default backend when there is display available and a fall-back backend when there is not, that applies without modifying the scripts (unless the scripts specifically select some backend).
**Is this possible?**

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Does it really hurt to run a script at the top of all your scripts that chooses the right backend? See also [this](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Non-X11-fallback-on-import-td22287.html) discussion

Comment: have multiple copies of your rcparams file configured how ever you want.  Run a script when you login which puts the correct one in place before starting python.

Comment: The problem with setting it up at the beginning of the scripts is that then you need to adapt every script to run in this environment. Of course is not an incredibly hard task, but since the computer is always the same and the scripts keep varying, a way to set it up that is independent of the script would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would like matplotlib to have this fallback functionality as a setting somewhere, but I can't find anything.

So I made this script that you can put in `.bashrc` to fall back automatically if `DISPLAY` is not set.

You can adapt the backends to use with and without `DISPLAY` (replace `TkAgg` and `Agg`) and change the location of matplotlibrc (two places).

```
# create the settings file if it doesn't exist
cp -n /etc/matplotlibrc ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
# set the backend to use depending on $DISPLAY
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]; then backend=Agg; else backend=TkAgg; fi
# find the line(s) starting with 'backend' and replaced them
sed -i "s/^backend.*/backend      : $backend/" ~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
```

This is particularly useful if you have a homedir that you use through `ssh` and through graphical interface (like the question); otherwise you can just create a static `matplotlibrc`.