# matplotlib RuntimeError in cron job before actual import

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, cron

I have a module I'm writing that uses matplotlib.  However, I need it to work with a display(e.g. command-line execution), or when theres no display ( SGE/qsub cluster job, or a cron job).

I found this answer ( [Automatic detection of display availability with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257385/automatic-detection-of-display-availability-with-matplotlib) ), which works for the command-line execution and within a cluster job.  But, in a cron job, it fails to properly import matplotlib, and seems to throw an exception before I import it.

In the cronjob, I try to import my module with the following script:

```
import os    
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = 'path/to/my/module/dir:%s' % os.environ['PYTHONPATH']

print 'now loading mymodule...'
import mymodule
```

and mymodule.py just has the code from the earlier linked answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

print 'testing import method...'
import matplotlib
r = 0
try :
  r = os.system('python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.figure()"')
except RuntimeError :
  pass
print 'r=%d' % r
if r != 0:
  print 'matplotlib: running in cluster, using Agg!'
  matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get this error message from the cron service:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/afs/ifh.de/user/u/user/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/afs/ifh.de/user/u/user/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/afs/ifh.de/user/u/user/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 14, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "/afs/ifh.de/user/u/user/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 16, in <module>
    import gtk; gdk = gtk.gdk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
now loading mymodule...
testing import method...
r=256
matplotlib: running in cluster, using Agg!
```

I think its trying and failing to import matplotlib, which is throwing a RuntimeError, *before* getting to my code in mymodule.py .  I can see that it gets to my code and runs it, but the Traceback message makes me nervous.

Why is it loading matplotlib(and crashing) before I tell it to(with Agg)?  How can I fix/hide that traceback message?

Answer (score 0):

As a dirty trick to hide the traceback message, just pipe all errors in the cronjob to `/dev/null`:

```
script.py 2> /dev/null
```